# Por que está retornando None no final da execução do programa?

Tags: python, funções

Eu gostaria de entender porque ao executar este código estou recebendo um valor de None no final da execução, mesmo o código rodando corretamente o que foi proposto pelo exercício.

-> Crie uma função que receba como parâmetro um valor inteiro e gere como saída n linhas com pontos de exclamação, conforme o exemplo abaixo (para n = 5)

```
!

!!

!!!

!!!!

!!!!!
```

---

```
def exclamacoes(quant):
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        print('!' * i)

num = int(input('Digite: '))

print(exclamacoes(num))
```

Ao final da execução do meu código, utilizando como exemplo o valor 5, estou recebendo:

```
!

!!

!!!

!!!!

!!!!! 

None
```

Comment: existe um erro de lógica, você declarou a variável `quant` como parâmetro do método _exclamacoes_ porém está utilizando `num`.

Comment: Tem mais, aqui `print(exclamacoes(num))` você manda imprimir o retorno da função `exclamacoes()` porém essa função não possui instrução de retorno e em python uma função que termine sem definir um valor de retorno implicitamente retorna `None`. Talvez quisesse apenas fazer `exclamacoes(num)`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu tentei explicar isso na resposta. Tem algum feedback? Eu não encontrei referência dessa citação que eu fiz, mas em resumo é o mesmo que tentou explicar.

Comment: @Danizavtz, na [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#:~:text=Be%20consistent%20in,function%20(if%20reachable)%3A) instrui *...Seja consistente nas declarações de retorno. Todas as instruções de retorno em uma função devem retornar uma expressão ou nenhuma delas deve. Se qualquer instrução de retorno retornar uma expressão, quaisquer instruções de retorno em que nenhum valor seja retornado devem declarar isso explicitamente como `return None`, e uma instrução de retorno explícita deve estar presente no final da função (se alcançável)...*

Comment: @Danizavtz, Nesse texto [Implicit return Statements](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#implicit-return-statements) é explicado em detalhes o funcionamento dos retornos implícitos de funções.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, já vou adicionar as referências e uma tradução livre do texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função *exclamacoes* não possui um valor de retorno, e por padrão a linguagem de programação `Python` sempre retorna algum valor ao declarar uma função ou método.

Segundo o site [realpython](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#implicit-return-statements):

> Uma função Python sempre terá um valor de retorno. Portanto, se você não usar explicitamente um valor de retorno em uma instrução de retorno, ou se omitir totalmente a palavra chave `return`, o Python retornará implicitamente um valor padrão para você. Esse valor de retorno padrão é `None`.

Quando você declara uma função ou método em Python implicitamente adiciona um `return None` ao final da execução da ultima linha de sua função ou método.

Então quando você está executando a linha:

```
print(exclamacoes(5))
```

Ele imprime 6 linhas.

as exclamações é a lógica que você implementou.

E o `None` que é o valor de retorno da função `exclamacoes()`

Já que você não declarou nenhum retorno.

Ex:

```
!
!!
!!!
!!!!
!!!!! <-- até aqui é a implementação da sua lógica para imprimir exclamações.
None <-- aqui é o valor de retorno da função exclamacoes()
```

Você pode re-escrever a função para que ela possua retorno, então o que será exibido em tela é o valor de retorno da função.

Ex:

```
def exclamacoes(quant):
    for i in range(1, quant + 1):
        print('!' * i)
    return 'pff'
```

Agora ao invocar a função `exclamacoes` temos a seguinte saída:

```
print(exclamacoes(5))
!
!!
!!!
!!!!
!!!!!
pff
```

---

Talvez o que realmente quer fazer é só invocar a função `exclamacoes`.

Ex:

```
num = int(input('Digite: '))
exclamacoes(num)
```