# Python: Porquê a função está retornando null após passar pelo else?

Tags: python, pycharm

gostaria de entender porquê a função retorna null após passar pelo else... quando não passa pelo else ela retorna o número certinho...

Exemplo de teste em que o retorno é null:

- digitar uma letra quando a nota for solicitada.
- Vai retornar que está incorreto.
- digitar um número.
- vai retornar null. =(

Exemplo de teste em que dá tudo certo:

- digitar um número de 0 a 10 quando a nota for solicitada.
- vai retornar o número. =)

'''

```
def formatar_nota() -> float:
    nota: str = input('NOTA: ')
    if not (nota.isalpha()) \
            and (
            (nota.strip().replace('-', '').replace('+', '').replace('.', '').isdigit()) and (
            0 <= float(nota) <= 10)):
        nota_validada: float = float(nota.strip().replace('-', '').replace('+', ''))
        return nota_validada
    else:
        print(f'Digite um número entre 0 e 10!')
        formatar_nota()

print(formatar_nota())
```

'''

Comment: A função retorna `None` porque em python toda função quando termina e não foi executada uma instrução `return` ou foi executada uma instrução `return` sem atribuição de valor é implicitamente retornado o valor o `None` para a função. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/560144/137387

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que está retornando None no final da execução do programa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/560144/por-que-est%c3%a1-retornando-none-no-final-da-execu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-programa)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Pode deixar o seu else dessa forma:

```
print(f'Digite um número entre 0 e 10!')
return formatar_nota()
```

Comment: Obrigada!!! Não tinha pensado em chamar a função no retorno do else. Muito grata.